# Stoppable background timer/observable with RXAndroid

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

I am trying to create a repeating, background timer with RXAndroid. I have written code that executes at a specified interval in the background, but I cannot find a way to stop it.

```
Observer<Long> observer = new Observer<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {}

        @Override
        public void onNext(Long aLong) {

            Log.d(LOGTAG, "Interval:" +String.valueOf(aLong));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {}

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {}
    };


    Observable observable = Observable.interval(1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io());

    observable.subscribe(observer);
```

I would like to know please:

1. Is this the correct approach for creating a "timer" in RXAndroid to execute code periodically in the background?
2. How do I stop it?

Comment: *How do I stop it* Keep a reference to the `Disposable` and unsubscribe it when you want to stop.

Comment: Ah, can't believe i missed that - thanks @Blackbelt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is this the correct approach for creating a "timer" in RXAndroid to execute code periodically in the background?

**Yes,**

> 2. How do I stop it?

To cancel the observer in RxJava you have to use the reference of `Disposable`.

Which you can find in the `onSubscribe(Disposable d)`.

`onSubscribe()` will call whenever you subscribe to observable. in your case it is `observable.subscribe(observer)`.

In observer you have method `public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {}` which will provide reference of `Disposable`.
   Declare global instance of `Disposable`, and whenever you want to cancel call `Disposable::dispose()`.